# Possible root causes include a too low setting for -Xss and illegal cyclic inheritance dependencies

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

My app is quit big and using many jars and tools.
Platform - windows 2008 server, Spring , hibernate, Quarts, mysql, tomcat-7.35

When I deploy and start the server first time working perfectly,
but If I restart I am getting the below err

```
    SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/TestProject]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1114)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1673)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to complete the scan for annotations for web application [/TestProject]. Possible root causes include a too low setting for -Xss and illegal cyclic inheritance dependencies
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2109)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1981)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1947)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1932)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1326)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:369)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5179)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more
    Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.HashSet.<init>(HashSet.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateSCIsForCacheEntry(ContextConfig.java:2252)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateSCIsForCacheEntry(ContextConfig.java:2269)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateSCIsForCacheEntry(ContextConfig.java:2269)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateSCIsForCacheEntry(ContextConfig.java:2269)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateSCIsForCacheEntry(ContextConfig.java:2269)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateSCIsForCacheEntry(ContextConfig.java:2269)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateSCIsForCacheEntry(ContextConfig.java:2269)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateSCIsForCacheEntry(ContextConfig.java:2269)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateSCIsForCacheEntry(ContextConfig.java:2269)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateSCIsForCacheEntry(ContextConfig.java:2269)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateSCIsForCacheEntry(ContextConfig.java:2269)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateSCIsForCacheEntry(ContextConfig.java:2269)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateSCIsForCacheEntry(ContextConfig.java:2269)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateSCIsForCacheEntry(ContextConfig.java:2269)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateSCIsForCacheEntry(ContextConfig.java:2269)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateSCIsForCacheEntry(ContextConfig.java:2269)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateSCIsForCacheEntry(ContextConfig.java:2269)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateSCIsForCacheEntry(ContextConfig.java:2269)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateSCIsForCacheEntry(ContextConfig.java:2269)

    Feb 16, 2013 12:16:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    SEVERE: Error deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.35\webapps\TestProject
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[TestProject]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:904)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1114)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1673)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: does anybody know how to change -Xss value?

Comment: Did you checked the logs after changing logging level to understand which jar is causing problems. There is a bug https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53871 but logs might help you in identifying the jar which is causing problem

Comment: log level is in debug mode only. But not able to identify the root cause

Answer (score 14):

The stack trace says that tomcat is running out of stack space on the thread that is scanning your application looking for java based servlet configurations. There are three ways you can solve this problem.

- Increase the stack size `-Xss4m`
- Tell Tomcat not to scan your application if you are not using any java based Servlet configuration  add `metadata-complete="true"` to your web-app in web.xml
- Restrict what jar files tomcat scans. see http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/jar-scanner.html

**Update 1**

you need to pass -Xss4m to your jvm to set the stack size, -Xss10m would set it to 10mb.

I am using Hibernate and Spring in my application too with annotations, the scanning that tomcat does is to look for Servlet 3.0 annotations so you can still restrict things while using hibernate and spring annotations, since hibernate and spring annoations are scanned for by spring and hibernate.

If you are running tomcat as a windows service you will need, to pass the arguments via procrun since that is the executable that is launching the jvm. The docs for procrun are at http://commons.apache.org/daemon/procrun.html. tomcat7.exe is really procrun.exe renamed, which means that all your jvm options are written to the registery under

> The basic Service definitions are maintained under the registry key:
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\
>
> Additional parameters are stored in the registry at:
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Apache Software Foundation\ProcRun
>   2.0\\Parameters
>
> On 64-bit Windows procrun always uses 32-bit registry view for storing
>   the configuration. This means that parameters will be stored inside:
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Apache Software
>   Foundation\ProcRun 2.0\

**Update 2**

Tomcat has been tweaking how the scanner works between point releases. try rolling forward through the versions 7.25,7.26 ... etc to find the version at which it breaks, the go through the release notes for that version to see if they changed how the scanner works.

Another thing you can try doing, is to create another war file which has all the third party jars in your WEB-INF\lib but not your code. See if you get that error if you start up, and if you do then should file a bug report with tomcat and make available to them your sample project that replicates the problem, on github or some other free code hosting system. I am sure if there is a bug they will fix it.

Comment: last 6 months app worked well, last build onwards only it is happening, But we dont have much code change in the last build. I have veriferd code as well. Could you plz tell me how to change stack size. My windows server have 4gb ram. Surprise is when I restart the tomcat CPU Ussage 100%. your 2nd and  3rd option not passible for my case. Since we are using spring and hibenate anotations

Comment: my project is working perfectely in tomcat7.25 but not in 7.35

Answer (score 9):

To fix this for TC Server 2.9, running Tomcat 7.0.39 I restricted the jars to skip during startup for the context config using:

```
org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.jarsToSkip=*.jar
```

in catalina.properties.

Comment: And Tomcat 7.0.56. I worked out the specific jar rather than using a wildcard: pdfbox-app-1.8.1.jar caused this... something to do with a version of bouncy castle being inside the jar

Comment: If you have Spring in your application, simplily you can't desactive this property.

Answer (score 2):

In My case iTextpdf JAR(5.06 version) causing problem as it had dependancy on `org.bouncyCastle.*.jar` and it was creating cyclic dependancy.

After updating it to `5.5.6` version, worked perfectly.
If you are adding maven dependancy , clean and update maven project.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I have moved from that project. So not able to validate. may be answer coud be correct. We also used bouncycastle. +1

Answer (score 0):

I'm not running Tomcat as a Windows service, so to pass `-Xss10m` through, I edited catalina.bat, towards the bottom:

```
:doJpda
if not "%SECURITY_POLICY_FILE%" == "" goto doSecurityJpda
%_EXECJAVA% %JAVA_OPTS% %CATALINA_OPTS% %JPDA_OPTS% %DEBUG_OPTS% -Djava.endorsed.dirs="%JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS%" -Xss10m -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" -

Dcatalina.base="%CATALINA_BASE%" -Dcatalina.home="%CATALINA_HOME%" -Djava.io.tmpdir="%CATALINA_TMPDIR%" %MAINCLASS% %CMD_LINE_ARGS% %ACTION%
goto end
```