# Unidentified illegal cyclic inheritance dependencies (Migrating jav webapps from resin 3.1.9 to tomcat 7.0.7)

Tags: java, tomcat

I am migrating my java webpass from server resin 3.1.9 to tomcat 7.0.70. This is the log of errors:

```java
Agu 11, 2016 10:35:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.70\webapps\wwwroot_admin
Agu 11, 2016 10:35:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/wwwroot_admin]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1260)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:2002)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to complete the scan for annotations for web application [/wwwroot_admin] due to a StackOverflowError. Possible root ca
uses include a too low setting for -Xss and illegal cyclic inheritance dependencies. The class hierarchy being processed was [org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1OutputStream->org.
bouncycastle.asn1.DEROutputStream->java.io.FilterOutputStream->java.io.OutputStream->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Obj
ect->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->jav
a.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.O
bject->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->j
ava.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang
.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object-
>java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.la
ng.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Objec
t->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.
lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Obj
ect->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.checkHandlesTypes(ContextConfig.java:2176)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2122)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1983)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1944)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1929)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1328)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:887)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:387)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5503)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
        ... 10 more

Agu 11, 2016 10:35:55 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
SEVERE: Error deploying web application directory D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.70\webapps\wwwroot_admin
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[l
ocalhost].StandardContext[/wwwroot_admin]]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:903)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1260)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:2002)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Agu 11, 2016 10:35:55 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.70\webapps\wwwroot_admin has finished in 1,189 ms
```

I have already increased the stack size by adding:

```
set CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms1024m -Xmx4096m
```

in files `%CATALINA_HOME%/bin/catalina.bat` and also `setenv.bat`.

My question is how to solve several errors, the illegal cyclic inheritance error? Which class causing the error? And how can i fix these?

Comment: Your error message calls for increase in `-Xss` (thread stack size).  Have you tried it?

Comment: check for this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14910757/possible-root-causes-include-a-too-low-setting-for-xss-and-illegal-cyclic-inher)